# JavaScript code is not working in angular .ts file

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, jquery-animate, angular-animations

> **this is my HTML Code **

```
<section class="funfactSection">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col text-left pt-5 pdl115 pdb38">
                <div class="row mrm110px">
                    <div class="col-xl-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <div class="icon_box_02">
                            <i class="fal fa-users"></i>
                            <h3><span><span data-counter="140" class="timer">140</span>M+</span> Happy Users</h3>
                            <p>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod temp or
                                incididunt.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="icon_box_02">
                            <i class="fal fa-coffee"></i>
                            <h3><span><span data-counter="300" class="timer">300</span>M+</span> Cup Coffee</h3>
                            <p>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod temp or
                                incididunt.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xl-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <div class="icon_box_02 ">
                            <i class="fal fa-hamburger"></i>
                            <h3><span><span data-counter="200" class="timer">200</span>M+</span> Project Done</h3>
                            <p>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod temp or
                                incididunt.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="icon_box_02">
                            <i class="fal fa-code"></i>
                            <h3><span><span data-counter="500" class="timer">500</span>M+</span> Line Code</h3>
                            <p>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod temp or
                                incididunt.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

> **this is my angular component typescript file**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-fact',
  templateUrl: './home-fact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-fact.component.css']
})
export class HomeFactComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let skl: boolean = true;
    $('.timer').appear();
    $('.timer').on('appear', () => {
      if (skl) {
        $('.timer').each(() => {
          var $this = $(this);
          $({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ Counter: $this.attr('data-counter') }, {
            duration: 3000,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function () {
              var num = Math.ceil(this.Counter).toString();
              $this.html(num);
            }
          });
        });
        skl = false;
      }
    });
  }

}
```

> ****My Problem:** **
> First time is work fine when document/angular project is loaded but whenever i navigate to another component and come back from another component to it then it's not working.
> in this we used two library npm i jquery@2.2.4 and npm i jquery.appear
> Please help
>
> i want that it's work fine whenever i came back from another component to it;

Comment: It has nothing to do with the language, TS or JS , let alone the actual file extensions.. All the code running is Javascript all the time. Angular does not recreate components or even execute all the life cycle hooks unless you fully navigated away from them, causing them to be disposed of. Since jQuery, and again this nothing to do with it being written in javascript, isn't tied into the angular change detection mechanism your component isn't updating. The quick and dirty fix is to change the routers component creation strategy to not reuse the instance of the component. Also stop with jQuery

Comment: can you suggest me solution for this.